# Interfacing IR RC5 remote with STM32

Tags: stm32, infrared, remote, rc5

I am interfacing IR remote which works on RC5 protocol with `STM32F405VG`. I have a PCB where I am using [TSOP 1738](http://www.micropik.com/PDF/tsop17xx.pdf) to receive RC5 packets. I have connected the CRO. Whenever I am pressing any buttons on the remote, I am receiving the full packet.

Now to interface this on the PCB . I using  timer to capture the duration between the rising/ falling edges. But it seems not to be working. I am new to the STM32 environment. Can anyone please check and confirm if the configuration set for the timers are correct or not. Here is the code:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;   //For GPIO pin where TSOP is connected
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;   //Global interrupts
TIM_ICInitTypeDef TIM_ICInitStructure; //Timers

/*  Clock Configuration for TIMER */
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3 , ENABLE);

RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
/* Pin configuration: input floating */
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;    //Pin2 of Port C
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;   //Input mode
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOC,&GPIO_InitStructure);    //Init GPIO

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC,GPIO_PinSource2,GPIO_AF_TIM3);
NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_2);

/* Enable the TIM global Interrupt */
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM3_IRQn ;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

int PrescalerValue=0;
PrescalerValue = (uint16_t) ((SystemCoreClock / 2) / 6000000) - 1;

/* TIMER frequency input */
TIM_PrescalerConfig(TIM3, PrescalerValue, TIM_PSCReloadMode_Immediate);

/* TIM configuration */
TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel = TIM_Channel_1;
TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity = TIM_ICPolarity_Falling;
TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter = 0x0;
 TIM_PWMIConfig(TIM3, &TIM_ICInitStructure); 

/* Select the TIM3 Input Trigger: TI1FP1 */
TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM3, TIM_TS_TI1FP1);

/* Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode */
TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM3, TIM_SlaveMode_Reset);

/* Enable the Master/Slave Mode */
TIM_SelectMasterSlaveMode(TIM3, TIM_MasterSlaveMode_Enable);

/* Configures the TIM Update Request Interrupt source: counter overflow */
TIM_UpdateRequestConfig(TIM3,  TIM_UpdateSource_Regular);

/* Set the TIM auto-reload register for each IR protocol */
TIM3->ARR = RC5TimeOut;

/* Clear update flag */
TIM_ClearFlag(TIM3, TIM_FLAG_Update);

/* Enable TIM3 Update Event Interrupt Request */
TIM_ITConfig(TIM3, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);

/* Enable the CC2/CC1 Interrupt Request */
TIM_ITConfig(TIM3, TIM_IT_CC2, ENABLE);
TIM_ITConfig(TIM3, TIM_IT_CC1, ENABLE);

/* Enable the timer */
TIM_Cmd(TIM3, ENABLE);
```

And here is the code of Timer3 interrupt handler

```
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  static uint32_t ICValue1;
  static uint32_t ICValue2;

 /* IC1 Interrupt*/
 if((TIM_GetFlagStatus(TIM3, TIM_FLAG_CC1) != RESET))
 {
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_10);
     TIM_ClearFlag(TIM3, TIM_FLAG_CC1);
    /* Get the Input Capture value */
   ICValue2 = TIM_GetCapture1(TIM3);


}  /* IC2 Interrupt */   
 else  if((TIM_GetFlagStatus(TIM3, TIM_FLAG_CC2) != RESET))
 {
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_10);
   TIM_ClearFlag(TIM3, TIM_FLAG_CC2);
   /* Get the Input Capture value */
  ICValue1 = TIM_GetCapture2(TIM3);

 } 
/* Checks whether the TIM3 flag is set or not.*/
else if ((TIM_GetFlagStatus(TIM3, TIM_FLAG_Update) != RESET))
{ 
  /* Clears the TIM3 pending flags*/
  TIM_ClearFlag(TIM3, TIM_FLAG_Update);


 }

}
```

After initializing, interrupt handler starts working but IC1 or IC2 interrupt event never occurred even though I keep pressing the remote key. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
```

To this:

```
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
```

To complete connection of the input capture alternative function mode.